# Is there any way to get the key value of the array element that called a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, key

I am trying to reduce code size on a webpage by reading in an xml that contains a variable number of objects.  In the javascript code I create an array to hold each of the objects and loop through the xml data to create each object.

I loop through the number of xml nodes to create that many objects and the object functions (mouseover, onclick, etc) but in the functions I use the same index variable to access the current objects properties, but when the function is actually called that index variable is no longer within my range.

Is there anyway I can get the calling object's key (index) value?

```
for(index=0, index < scenes.length; index+=1)
{
 this.thumbs[index] = document.createElement('div');
//setup more properites
this.thumbs_image[index] = document.createElement('img');
//more setup
this.thumbs[index].onmouseover = function(){
me.thumbs_image[index].src = scenes[index].attributes.getNamedItem("src").nodeValue;     //THIS IS THE PROBLEM - WHEN the function is actually called index is no longer the correct index of the array element
}
}
```

The code outside of the function onmouseover works, and it works if I hardcode the index within the onmouseover.

I tried creating a separate function with the index passed as parameter, but when I assign the function dynamically I still assign with index as I can't think of another way and this doesn't work either:

```
this.thumb[index].onmouseover = myFunction(index);

myFunction=function(i){
me.thumbs_image[i].src = scenes[i].attributes.getNamedItem("src").nodeValue;
}
```

Is there any way within the onmouseover to get the key of the element calling it?

I'm hoping there is an obvious solution that I am just overlooking - any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:** replace this:

```
this.thumbs[index].onmouseover = function(){
  me.thumbs_image[index].src = scenes[index].attributes.getNamedItem("src").nodeValue;
}
```

with this:

```
this.thumbs[index].onmouseover = (function(i) {
  return function() {
    me.thumbs_image[index].src = scenes[index].attributes.getNamedItem("src").nodeValue;
  };
})(i);
```

The function wrapper will capture the value of the variable `i` in a closure, so that you can access that value (as opposed the non-existent variable `i`) at the time the handler is invoked.

**Second solution:** `onmouseover` (and all other event handlers) will receive one argument, which is the event. The event knows where it originated. Try this:

```
this.thumbs[index].onmouseover = function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target);
}
```

I recommend the second solution in this particular case, but the pattern in the first solution is important to know about - never create functions that depend on the loop counter directly in a loop, instead always have a function call to capture the loop counter's value instead.

Comment: The first solution did not work for me although maybe I implemented it incorrectly.  The second one did after I set the ID attribute for each.  Thanks for the help!